# Ionic V1 : Unable to build the ionic APK Cannot find module './array/insert'

Tags: ionic-framework

Hi I am trying to build an application based on ionic V1 framework. The application while building throwing following wrror on console.

```
> ionic-v1 build
[11:49:25] Cannot load gulp: Error: Error in module: .\gulpfile.js:
Error: Cannot find module './array/insert'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sagar\FourWin\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\mout\array.js:23:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
[11:49:25] Cannot run sass task: missing in gulpfile.js
```

My package.json file is this:

```
{
.
.
.
"dependencies": {
"gulp": "^3.5.6",
"gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
"gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
"gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
"gulp-rename": "^1.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/v1-toolkit": "1.0.10",
"bower": "^1.3.3",
"gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
"shelljs": "^0.3.0"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
"cordova-plugin-whitelist",
"cordova-plugin-console",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar",
"cordova-plugin-device",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
"ionic-plugin-keyboard"
],
"cordovaPlatforms": []
}
```

How to deal with this problem. I tried `npm install` to see if any package missing but still same error persists

Answer (score 1):

After doing a work around for about 4 hours more, i figured out the problem. I am not sure by what activity the problem has been solved but i am listing my steps here

1. I have individually upgraded all the associated plugins of gulp as part of dependencies in package.json file.
2. Problem got resolved but then new problem arrived where it is not finding the Sass file module required to compile sass

   ```
   Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with 
   Unsupported runtime (57)
   ```
3. Then i changed my gulp-sass version to `"gulp-sass": "^3.1.0"` from `"gulp-sass": "^2.0.4"` in package.json
4. then i did `npm install`
5. `ionic cordova build android`

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share with us the content of your gulpfile.js file ? It may be that an internal dependency is not included anymore, as Ionic V1 begin to be old...